# Redirect to subdomain or subdir on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There is a dashboard that allows you to redirect based on rules like from a subdomain as a base to a subdirectory/path. No it's not with a listener on an Application Load Balancer.

I have a bunch of them set up and for the life of me can't figure out which dashboard.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what "dashboard" you are referring to? maybe screenshot?

Comment: lol how would I provide a screenshot to a dashboard that I can't find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to click on this button.

The most ridiculous spot to put something so crucial, especially when "edit" next to "Add listener" is a completely different editing menu.

[image]